# Symfony Work with Multiple Entity Managers

Tags: symfony

I'm using symfony 6 and I'd like to use 2 databases, but I can't.

Here is my `.env`:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/bdd?serverVersion=MariaDB-10.4.11"     CUSTOMER_DATABASE_URL="mysql://username:password@127.0.0.1:3306/bdd2?serverVersion=MariaDB-10.4.11"
```

Here is my doctrine.yaml

```
when@test:
    doctrine:
        dbal:
            url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
            connections:
                default:
                    url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                clients:
                    url: '%env(resolve:CLIENTS_DATABASE_URL)%'
            default_connection: default
```

Here is my CustomerController

```
namespace App\\Controller;

use App\\Entity\\Clients;
use Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\AbstractController;
use Symfony\\Component\\HttpFoundation\\Response;
use Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Annotation\\Route;

class CustomerController extends AbstractController
{

    #[Route('/clients', name: 'clients_liste', methods: ['GET'])]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        // Assurez-vous que vous avez correctement configuré les connexions et les entités pour "clients"
        $entityManagerCustomer = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('clients');
        $clientsRepository = $entityManagerCustomer->getRepository(Client::class);
    
        // Récupérer tous les clients de la table "client" de la base de données "clients"
        $clients = $clientsRepository->findAll();
    
        return $this->render('customer/index.html.twig', [
            'clients' => $clients,
        ]);
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method AppControllerCustomerController::getDoctrine()
```

I'd like to know if I'm using the wrong method, and if anyone can help me, I'd love to hear from you. Thank you very much!

Do not hesitate to tell me if it's not clear

Comment: In Symfony 6 the AbstractController::getDoctrine method has been removed.  You can check the docs to see how to access an entity manager.  Be aware that using multiple entity managers can be tricky.  Even after you get past this basic mistake you may run into additional issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Should i create another project with my bdd2 and then make an API ?